# How to remount logical volumes again after using lvremove?

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted, lvm

In order to make a smaller partition for a smaller clonezilla image, I booted from a ubuntu-live USB, unmounted the locked partitions with `lvremove` (don't recall exact names, but similar to: 'root' and 'swap_1') and resized the boot partition from 465GB to 108GB.

After that I tried rebooting (without the ubuntu-live USB) but the computer couldn't boot anymore because it couldn't find any mounted drive. It displayed a "Gave up waiting for root device" etc initramfs error.

How can I mount the partitions again?

What GParted looks like:

[image: screenshot GParted]

What `system-config-lvm` looks like:

[image: screenshot LVM]

Here some terminal outputs that could be useful:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo vgscan
Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
```

...

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo pvs
PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree  
/dev/sda5  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  108.00g 108.00g
```

...

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -lu

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004fdc0

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   976771071   488134657    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   226996223   113247232   8e  Linux LVM
```

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think `lvremove` "unmounts" volumes - AFAIK it actually removes them from the VG. Can you actually still see any logical volumes (e.g. using `sudo lvscan`)? (You may need to activate the volume group first i.e. `sudo vgchange -ay`). You may be able to restore the volumes, for example using the process described here: [How to recover logical volume deleted with lvremove](http://serverfault.com/questions/223361/how-to-recover-logical-volume-deleted-with-lvremove) but I have never personally tried it.

Comment: thanks @steeldriver - i followed this answer http://serverfault.com/a/583578/370845 and was able to restore my logical volumes from a backup!

Answer (score 1):

Restore deleted logical volumes from backup by following [this answer to “How to recover logical volume deleted with lvremove”](//serverfault.com/a/583578/370845):

> **Example:**
>
> 1 - I have removed my logical volume!
>
> ```
> $ sudo lvremove /dev/vg1/debian.root
> ```
>
> 2 - First thing to do is, look for the archive file at
>   /etc/lvm/archive/vg1_(xxxxx).vg. I can do that, just looking the date
>   that i have removed the logical volume!
>
> ```
> $ sudo ls -l /etc/lvm/archive |more
> ```
>
> 3- I found it!
>
> ```
> -rw------- 1 root root 16255 Mar 20 14:29 vg1_00223-235991429.vg
> -rw------- 1 root root 16665 Mar 20 16:49 vg1_00224-748876387.vg
> -rw------- 1 root root 17074 Mar 20 16:49 vg1_00225-931666169.vg
> -rw------- 1 root root 17482 Mar 20 16:50 vg1_00226-1238302012.vg
> -rw------- 1 root root 18081 **Mar 20 21:57 vg1_00227-2048533959.vg**
> ```
>
> Date where i did the lvremove!!!...it was a minutes ago..
>
> 4 - Let's see the file!
>
> ```
> $ sudo head /etc/lvm/archive/vg1_00227-2048533959.vg
> *# Generated by LVM2 version 2.02.95(2) (2012-03-06): Thu Mar 20 21:57:58 2014
> contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
> version = 1
> description = **"Created *before* executing 'lvremove /dev/vg1/debian.root'"**
> creation_host = "server"  # Linux server 3.8.0-35-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 01:24:59 UTC 2013 x86_64
> creation_time = 1395363478    # Thu Mar 20 21:57:58 2014*
> ```
>
> 5 - Make a test before recover it!
>
> ```
> $ sudo vgcfgrestore vg1 --test -f /etc/lvm/archive/vg1_00227-2048533959.vg
> Test mode: Metadata will NOT be updated and volumes will not be
> (de)activated.   **Restored volume group vg1**
> ```
>
> 6 - Ok, now repeat the command line, without the (--test)
>
> ```
> $ sudo vgcfgrestore vg1 -f /etc/lvm/archive/vg1_00227-2048533959.vg
> **Restored volume group vg1**
> ```
>
> 7 - Check it!
>
> ```
> $ sudo lvscan |grep debian
> ACTIVE            '/dev/vg1/debian.root' [7,81 GiB] inherit
> ```
>
> 8 - If the logical was not active, do it!
>
> ```
> $ sudo lvchange -a y /dev/vg1/debian.root
> ```